# Is there a way to free a route in Angular so that the router doesn't process it?

Tags: angular, angular8

This might be an odd use case, but it could also be a common one. I have a domain, say `example.com`. I want to have an Angular 8 app in the root but I want to have a Wordpress installation in `example.com/blog`.

Now, since in `example.com` there's an Angular app if I try to navigate to `example.com/blog`, either by typing the url in the browser bar directly or by trying to navigate from the app using JavaScript (with a `window.open()` for example), what I get is a blank page rendered by Angular.

So... Is there a way to free the `/blog` route from the Angular Router?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about angular router, but this seems like a server-side job.

Your server should send `/blog` requests to your blog domain and rest all to your `index.html`(Angular app).

Comment: Hmmm... So an .htaccess file well configured might be the solution. I'll research this angle.

Answer (score 0):

I found a really easy way to do it. Instead of trying to redirect to `/blog` I'm using `/blog/index.php`. Then, the .htaccess present in the blog kicks in and loads perfectly.

But I don't know how much of a "hack" this solution is and wonder if there's a better, more elegant, one.